# JavaScript помощь

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

не знаю js. Есть поле для ввода тегов, при создании еще одного - js-скрипт к нему не применяется. Неизвестно сколько таких полей на странице может быть, как сделать, чтобы при создании нового input к нему сразу применялись все настройки?

Код тут
https://codepen.io/softwebtuts/pen/ErgZme

```js
$('[name=tags]').tagify();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 480px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

tags {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding-right: 0.3em 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: text;
}

tags:hover {
  border-color: #CCC;
}

@keyframes tags--bump {
  30% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #E5E5E5;
  }
}

tags tag {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: .13s ease-out;
  animation: .3s tags--bump 1 ease-out;
}

tags tag>span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  transition: .13s ease-out;
}

tags tag:hover span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #7AC3FF inset;
  transition: 50ms;
}

tags tag.tagify--noAnim {
  animation: none;
}

tags tag.tagify--hide {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .3s;
}

@keyframes tagify--pulse {
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #7AC3FF inset;
  }
}

tags tag.tagify--mark span {
  animation: .4s tagify--pulse 3 ease-out;
}

tags tag x {
  font: 14px/15px Serif;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(0.5em - 2px);
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: .2s;
}

tags tag x::after {
  content: "\00D7";
}

tags tag x:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #cc8282;
}

tags tag x:hover+span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #D39494 inset;
  transition: .2s;
}

tags input,
tags textarea {
  border: 0;
  display: none;
}

tags div {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
}

tags .input {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tags .input.placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

tags .input.placeholder::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
  max-width: 200px;
}

tags .input::after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  transform: translatex(6px);
  transition: .15s ease-out;
}

tags .input::before {
  content: '\200B';
}

tags .input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Tiny-Text-Field-Based-Tags-Input-Plugin-For-jQuery-Tagify/jQuery.tagify.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Tagify - Tags Input</h1>
  <input name='tags' placeholder='write some tags' value='jQuery,Script,Net, Softweb Tuts'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю стоит перебирать все элементы и к ним вызывать данную функцию. Скорее всего это делается короче на чистом jQ, но я его не совсем помню.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name=tags]')
  .forEach(el => $(el).tagify());
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]